# Nginx access from specific IP forbidden with deny all

Tags: nginx

If I put a comment in front of denying (in both lines) I can access the web page
from 10.10.10.94, if I remove the comment in front of denying then I'm getting 403 forbidden access forbidden by rule, according to the documentation this should work but for some reason, it doesn't, any hint?

```
location / {
          allow 10.10.10.94;
          deny 10.10.0.0/16;
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5007;
      }
      location /api/ {
          allow 10.10.10.94;
          deny 10.10.0.0/16;
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5006/;
      }
```

Comment: Did you restart the nginx?

Comment: if you mean service, yes i did, systemctl restart nginx

Comment: started working after i restarted whole server ?